# Отключить reCAPTCHA при входе по номеру телефона Firebase

Tags: java, kotlin, firebase, auth

я пытаюсь создать авторизацию в Firebase по номеру телефона, но сталкиваюсь с "проверкой устройства", которая мешает и крайне неудобна.[image: Проверка приложения]

В документации Firebase вроде бы нашёл решение этой проблемы - добавить setAppVerificationDisabledForTesting(true); Браузер и правда больше не открывается, но теперь не приходит sms и получаю ошибку "This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details." Подскажите, как я могу решить свою проблему с проверкой в браузере.

Comment: Никак, этот метод может использоваться только для тестов. `Note that even though reCAPTCHA and/or SafetyNet are disabled, using a real phone number will still fail to complete sign in. Only fictional phone numbers can be used with this API.` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66637629/5479247